# How to load Leaflet layer attribution from server?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have my own Leaflet tile layer extension

```
L.TileLayer.Foo = L.TileLayer.extend({
    options: {
        ...
    },
    initialize: function (apiKey, options) {
        ...
        L.TileLayer.prototype.initialize.call(this, url, mergedOptions);
    },
    getAttribution: function() {
        return "hello!";
    }
});
```

Basically, Leaflet will at some point call `getAttribution` of all layers, and build attribution control. But what if I want to load attribution text (which shall `getAttribution` return) from server (based on `apiKey` provided to `initialize`)?

I dont see any asynchronous way (something to call from ajax success callback) in [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-attribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet doesn't have that kind of functionality. You need to implement AJAX call by yourself, then add attribution manually in xhr callback. So inside `getAttribution` will be something like:

```
AjaxCall.then(function(responce){
   leafletMap.attributionControl.addAttribution(responce.data.Attribution);
});
```

Comment: And when to call this? In initialize function? Can I be sure, that attributionControl will be already ready by the time of the callback?

Comment: `getAttribution` called within `layerAdd` function. Which is called when you add layer to map. And you cant't add anything until map instance s ready, same as an `attributionControl`.